# How is row operations the same as multiplying?

Tags: linear-algebra

En,En-1...E1A=I

How is subtracting rows adding rows same as multiplying by a matrix?
How is using elementary row operations same as multiplying with a matrix?
We want to perform E1A.
Lets say we have a 2 by 2 identity matrix and we want to perform the operation R1-R2.How is this same as multiplying it with another matrix A to get E1A

Comment: Your question is very short and difficult to understand. Can you explain what you mean with an example?

Comment: I have updated it now.

Comment: Your question is stronger related to the elementary operations of matrices. For a better understanding of this topic, you should read section 1.3 of the book Linear Algebra by Hoffman- Lunze.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$
and you want to subtract the third row twice from the second row, then take
$$E=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&-2\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and notice that using matrix multiplication you indeed get
$$EA=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}-2a_{31}&a_{22}-2a_{32}&a_{23}-2a_{33}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim**: For any elementary row operation, there is a unique matrix $E$ such that $EA$ is the result of applying the row operation to $A$ for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

*Proof*. This proof might leave you feeling like you've been mugged. First suppose that $E$ exists s.t. $EA$ is the result of applying the row operation to $A$ for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$. So, in particular, $E I_n$ is the result of applying the row operation to the identity matrix $I_n$. But you also know that $E I_n = E,$ so that in fact *if $E$ exists* then $E$ is the result of applying the corresponding row operation to $I_n$! It's then straightforward to verify that this matrix actually does what you want it to do.

Does that clear things up a bit?

Comment: Can you give me an example please. I don't really understand the proofs.

Comment: The example that Matja gave is a specific case of this: they showed that if $$E = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ then multiplying a matrix $A$ on the left by $E$ subtracts the third row twice from the second. Indeed, $E$ is exactly the result of subtracting the third row twice from the second for the identity $I_3$.